# Stitches by Shawn Mendes

Tags: music-video

In the music video for [Stitches by Shawn Mendes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbfpW0pbvaU), He appears to be fighting/being beat up by someone or something. What is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is love.

1. As stated here:
   http://www.billboard.com/articles/columns/pop-shop/6605873/shawn-mendes-stitches-video
2. The song's lyrics are descriptive too: http://genius.com/Shawn-mendes-stitches-lyrics. Quoting the comments by RainbowShimmers on that page:

> That got me thinking that the entire song is about his internal struggle of getting over the relationship breaking up. This was hinted at from the unseen force, as well as him being fixed at the end.

Edit:

3. Another site claims the same: http://radio.com/2015/06/25/shawn-mendes-stitches-video/

> What exactly is beating him up? Metaphorical love.

Comment: Where in the song's lyrics does it state this? Can you put those lyrics in your answer?

Comment: Is there a possibility that it isn't love that it may be himself beating him up because of him trusting and getting involved with the girl and because of the breakup And at the end he becomes clean because he gets over her and the breakup. Is this a possibility?